# How to set timezone in yii

Tags: php, yii, timezone

How to set proper format of timstamp into local time in GridView of yii

```
framework, for example:
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'add_time',                     // I see here a date/time from database not in my cyrrent timezone
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Guess, problem should be solved by setting proper global timezone in DB settings, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When someone is reffering to application property or application config it means "root" config variable, in this case timeZone.

Config part:

```
<?php
// in protected/config/main.php
return array(
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta'
    // Other configuration....
);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sanjay, thanks, but this setting didnt helped: time stored in DB in datetimefield and displays "asis" but in wrong timezone; so, I need some setting to set proper timezone in mysql

Comment: UPD: found sultion: Solution is to set initial db settings in config (main.php):
[code]
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
...
            'initSQLs'=>array("set time_zone='+03:00';"),      // for YII1
            'on afterOpen' => function($event) {                    // for YII2 
                $event->sender->createCommand('set time_zone="+03:00"')->execute();
            },
...

Comment: When you set default timezone in yii application then you do not need to set timezone on mysql server, Because when you save your data model to DB then yii automatically take application timezone.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2

Configure at common/config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'dateFormat' => 'php:j M Y',
        'datetimeFormat' => 'php:j M Y H:i',
        'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gridview to have the right timezone in column add_time, add the datetime like this

```
    'columns' => [
        'add_time:datetime',
    ],
```